# Notepad++ Regex to convert consecutive lines in comma separated, and separated lines in 1 enter space

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically, i need to convert this

> Vertebrates
>  Mammals
>  Fish
>  Birds
>  Amphibians
>   Reptiles
>  Fish
> Birds
>  Vertebrates
> Mamals
> Fish

into

> Vertebrates, Mammals, Fish, Birds, Amphibians, Reptiles 
> Fish,
>   Birds 
>  Vertebrates, Mammals, Fish

its possible using Notepad++ RegEx?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can. Have you tried writing the expression?

Comment: Yes, but I could not. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: May you post your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost-Extended format strings allows using conditional statements in replacement string which makes your Find / Replace action a piece of cake.

Find what:

```
(?<=\S)(\R)(?=\S)|(\R)+
```

Replace with:

```
(?1,:\2)
```

*As per [@bobblebubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s answer (which is removed by now) I'd like to go with word boundaries to avoid using lookarounds as well: `\b(\R)\b|(\R)+`*

Comment: A typo in back-referencing number fixed.

Comment: Works, Thanks so Much, Revo!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

Step 1:

```
Find: ([a-z])(\r\n|\r|\n)([A-Z])
Replace with: \1, \3
```

Step 2:

```
Find: (\r\n|\r|\n){2,}
Replace with: \1
```